# I can't get my if/else statement to work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a statement to say that if there's anything inside #process-description to show #process-work else hide it.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="process-work">
        <h2 id="process-title">Process Work</h2>
        <p id="process-description"></p>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
            'zeckoshop' : {
            'title' : 'zeckoShop',
            'description' : 'An all-in-one ecommerce platform designed to seamlessly integrate with your business operations.',
            'link' : 'http://darrenbachan.com/playground/zeckoshop/index.html',
            'images': [
                '/images/zeckoshop/zeckoshop-1.jpg'
            ],
            'tags': [
                'Web Design',
                'Web Development'
            ],
            'process-description' : 'An all-in-one ecommerce platform designed to seamlessly integrate with your business operations.',
            'process-wireframes': [
                '/images/zeckoshop/zeckoshop-1.jpg'
            ]
        }


if('#process-work') {
            $('#process-description').html(projectData['process-description']).show();
        } else {
            $('#process-work').hide();
        }
```

Comment: if('#process-work') { is always true...

Comment: I think we're missing part of your JS

Comment: @juvian I'm not sure what that means

Comment: @cuniculus let me know what i'm missing, or it can be viewed at http://darrenbachan.com/js/main.js

Comment: ok, so the `'zeckoshop' : { } ` is wrapped in a `projects = {}`. I asked because the code above would be a syntax error by itself

Comment: @cuniculus any idea what's triggering the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when you click on a project? 

http://darrenbachan.com/

Comment: @juvian do you mind elaborating on your response?

Comment: '#process-work' is a string, strings are always truthy except ''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Cannot fix/debug this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222596/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-cannot-fix-debu)

Comment: @DarrenBachan please mark an answer or update accordingly here

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking fir this change in the code :

```
if($('#process-description').length) {
            $('#process-description').html(projectData['process-description']).show();
        } else {
            $('#process-work').hide();
        }
```

Comment: I can't tell if this is working. I'm getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" console error. I was hoping the if/else statement would fix it.

http://darrenbachan.com/ if you click on the two first projects it opens fine but anything else gets that error. It's because it's looking for 'process-description' and 'process-wireframes' on each project and if it's not there it'll bug out. I shouldn't have to include it on each project to make the project work.

Comment: try adding `.html()` before `.length`

Comment: @cuniculus if($('#process-description').html().length) didn't work, it made the entire div not appear.