# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Cannot fix/debug this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://darrenbachan.com/

http://darrenbachan.com/js/main.js

I have no idea how to fix this. I don't know javascript at all to debug or understand other articles/threads. To get the error to appear, click onto a project that's not one of the first two and you'll see it in the console.

I have projects:

```
'zeckoshop' : {
            'title' : 'zeckoShop',
            'description' : 'An all-in-one ecommerce platform designed to seamlessly integrate with your business operations.',
            'link' : 'http://darrenbachan.com/playground/zeckoshop/index.html',
            'images': [
                '/images/zeckoshop/zeckoshop-1.jpg'
            ],
            'tags': [
                'Web Design',
                'Web Development'
            ],
            'process-description' : 'An all-in-one ecommerce platform designed to seamlessly integrate with your business operations.',
            'process-wireframes': [
                '/images/zeckoshop/zeckoshop-1.jpg'
            ]
        },

        'diamond-hand-car-wash' : {
            'title' : 'Diamond Hand Car Wash',
            'description' : 'Feeling luxurious is only one car wash away.',
            'link' : 'http://darrenbachan.com/playground/diamond-hand-car-wash/index.html',
            'images': [
                '/images/diamond-hand-car-wash/diamond-1.jpg'
            ],
            'tags': [
                'Web Design',
                'Web Development'
            ],
            'process-description' : 'test',
            'process-wireframes': [
                '/images/zeckoshop/zeckoshop-1.jpg'
            ]
        },

        'edutravel-for-credit' : {
            'title' : 'EduTravel For Credit',
            'description' : 'Innovative travel for credit. Completely engage in your learning through exploration and discovery.',
            'link' : '',
            'images': [
                '/images/edutravel-for-credit/edu-1.jpg',
                '/images/edutravel-for-credit/edu-2.jpg',
                '/images/edutravel-for-credit/edu-3.jpg',
                '/images/edutravel-for-credit/edu-4.jpg'
            ],
            'tags': [
                'Web Design',
                'Newsletter'
            ]
        },
```

Because 'process-description' and 'process-wireframes' aren't on project 'edutravel-for-credit' it creates this error.

The code that pulls this content is:

```
if($('#process-description').length) {
            $('#process-description').html(projectData['process-description']).show();
        } else {
            $('#process-work').hide();
        }
        $('#process-wireframes').empty('');

        $.each(projectData['process-wireframes'], function(item) {
            $('#process-wireframes').append('<div class="project-gallery"><img src='+projectData['process-wireframes'][item]+' /></div>')
        });
```

It spits content into this html:

```
<div id="process-work">
    <h2 id="process-title">Process Work</h2>
    <p id="process-description"></p>
    <div id="process-wireframes"></div>
</div>
```

I literally do not know how to debug this issue and can use any help I can get. Whether it be on here or a skype session or something. I need to display this content desperately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't debug "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221519/cant-debug-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Comment: you have asked the same question 4 times over now. Please desist. If you edit your question, it will move up, but please do NOT post again.  This post has been flagged for closure.

Comment: @RachelGallen I have edited my question before. One of the other questions was about specifically if/else statements, that led to this issue being discussed just a little bit in the comments. I will admit I did dupe this question, that's because even after editing the question to bump it I got no response, but I did this and I'm actually seeing people trying to help me. So sorry for breaking the site's rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the console error on chrome. Does the project load correctly despite the console error? I'm wondering if it's due to the hacky .length call to check if an element exists. However, to help you understand sort of what's going on...

The only place where you call `.length` is in this line of code:

`if($('#process-description').length) {`

Thus, somehow `$('#process-description')` is undefined. That's jQuery's way to retrieving the element in your html with ID "process-description" even though it's clearly in your HTML. So either jQuery isn't loaded, in which case I'd expect a compile error for `$ is not a function` or the element not to exist which wouldn't cause a console error, so you'll need to give us more information.

Comment: if you need clarification, please post a comment. this does not answer the [duplicate] question

Comment: That's not the only place where `.length` is called. It's also used internally by `$.each()`, so you'll get this error if you do `$.each(undefined, ...)`.

Comment: @barmar Good to know, thanks. I'm not as familiar with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Test whether the property exists before trying to iterate over it.

```
if (projectData['process-wireframes']) {
    $.each(projectData['process-wireframes'], function(item) {
        $('#process-wireframes').append('<div class="project-gallery"><img src='+projectData['process-wireframes'][item]+' /></div>')
    });
}
```

The error is happening because the code for `$.each` starts with:

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var value,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj );
```

When `obj` is undefined, the line `length = obj.length` gets an error.